# How vlang compile static binary?

Tags: vlang

i have tried `v -b native -prod hello.v` but most modules are not supported.

```
// hello.v
println('Hello, World!')
```

How vlang compile static binary ?

**Updated :**

i found another parameter `-freestanding` for static compile.

```
$ v -freestanding hello.v
$ file hello
hello: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, stripped
```

it can compile `hello.v` sucessfully but it flow error with `-prod` flag : `v -freestanding -prod hello.v`

any good idea ??

Comment: *"it can compile hello.v sucessfully but it flow error with -prod flag"* - ***what?***

Comment: if run "v -freestanding -prod hello.v" in Linux, build error :
==================
<artificial>:(.text+0x1): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
...
==================

Comment: Why not show the error then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. according to https://github.com/vlang/v/blob/master/doc/docs.md , `-freestanding` force static build :

   v -freestanding hello.v

   v -freestanding -prod hello.v
2. `native Backend` binaries would build static binary also.

   v -b native hello.v

   v -b native -prod hello.v

   v -b native -freestanding -prod hello.v

but, vlang is not mature enough, has too many bugs (ver 0.3.1). it would flow compilation error rightnow.
Hope will improve it later.

Answer (score 1):

Vlang comes with TCC, with the default setup. To do a normal compilation, you just need to do-

`v filename.v`

If you are using an alternate compiler, like say GCC, then it should be indicated. If you are getting errors, then you should show us what those errors are versus merely describing them, because others can't be sure what is really going on.

After we can see the actual image of the error, better help can be offered versus smearing the programming language or any false claims.

Comment: actually, i want static binary in linux, `v filename.v` would produce dynamic link binary